# "Child" documents in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

In RavenDb you can have multiple documents starting with the same key and create sub documents as described [here](http://mattwarren.org/2012/07/12/fun-with-ravendb-documents-keys/).

Do we have something similar in MongoDb?

Comment: Did you read through [these](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) capabilities? You can have subdocuments (although the total doc size must be smaller than 16MB as a BSON document). There are lots of great docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/crud/#document-orientation-concepts) as well.

Comment: Thanks. From what I've read there, [Materialized Paths](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/) should be the right one but I'm not sure at 100%.

Comment: Maybe post a small example of what you're wanting specifically if you can't find the answer in those docs? The dot notation in particular seems very similar to the RavenDB support (at least at a high level).